# Can I use a rescue harness for recreational climbing?

Tags: climbing, harness

I bought a sport harness and a rescue harness. I'm just wondering if i can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please give us some more details so you can get better answers? What type of conditions will you be climbing in? Have you used either type of harness before? Is there a specific region or location you'll be climbing? Do you climb alone? I don't climb so I can't advise you, but the experts here will appreciate as many details as you can give. Click on the gray "edit" word and the question will open up. Add anything you want in there, including pictures of the harnesses if you think that would help. Thanks for being with us!

Comment: More info about the rescue harness please. I've used industrial safety harnesses before, and would not want to climb in one. Is the rope attached at the front or the back? Is the attachment point meant for rope or a carabiner or something else? Is it rated for multiple falls? It heavier than a climbing harness, or A LOT heavier than a climbing harness?

Answer (score 4):

From a technical standpoint, it depends. For example, for the [Petzl Falcon](https://www.petzl.com/US/en/Professional/Harnesses/FALCON#.WURDlkBt8Xc) line of rescue harness, only the Mountain is rated fo *operations involving technical climbing*. The Ascent *is not suitable for progression using rock climbing techniques*. You will need to carefully read the instructions for your rescue harness to determine its suitability for rock climbing. Sport climbing harnesses lack many of the features (e.g., good padding and compatibility with a chest harness) and durability of rescue harnesses.

From a practical vantage, many SAR teams require dedicated equipment and using your rescue equipment for personal use would be a violation of their policies.